# Draw Graphics objects after image zoom

Tags: c#, graphics

I am using a picture box on my project, its working fine with zooming the image and any element already drawn on the image(line,shapes ......) the element position is transferred to the right position after zooming. the problem appears when i am trying to draw a line after zooming the image.After zooming the image in the picture box and trying to draw a line on the image, the drawn line is drawn with offset from the mouse position not in the same position.What is the solution for it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without any code to look at it, who knows?...

Comment: I would put picturebox into a panel and then draw the new line in the panel instead of the picture-box.  the picture box is only meant to contain one object (the picture) and not a picture and a line.

Comment: _the picture box is only meant to contain one object (the picture) and not a picture and a line_ This is nonsense. PBox can actually contain 3 levels: BackgroundImage, Image and drawn graphics. And it is meant to be drawn onto, which is why is it always Doublebuffered.